# How to change a boolean column to bit varying in PGSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

```
create table test_div1( i boolean)
    insert into test_div1 values('1');

ALTER TABLE test_div1 ALTER i TYPE bit varying  USING (i::text::bit varying );
```

//not working getting error.
please help

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting `error: "t" is not a valid binary digit`, postgres couldn't automatically cast `true` to `1`

what you need to do is handle the conversion yourself like this

```
create table test_div1( i boolean)

insert into test_div1 values('1');

insert into test_div1 values(false), ('1'), (true), ('0');

ALTER TABLE test_div1 ALTER i TYPE bit varying  USING (case when i = true then B'1' else B'0' end);
```

here is a working example https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wukNuibgNsJqzydNqz4eFy/0